# dynamic model relations in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, relationship, mongoose-schema

I have the following models/schema in my mongodb express application. The first one is for events:

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  createdBy: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
  }
});
```

The second one is for Users:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdEvents: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Event'
    }
  ]
});
```

When I am listing events I want to get details of the user who created them. Right now I am using  findById() method to get the user and add that user data to the results. Following the same thing while listing the users. Is there a way to achieve this without writing code like embedding documents etc ? Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use populate method

```
User.findById(id)
    .populate('createdEvents')
    .then(userWithEvents => {
      ... // use result here
    })
    .catch(err => {
      ... // handle error here
    })
```

[Edit] this will give you user with his events, if you want events with user data you should do same thing from reverse side

```
Event.find(...)
    .populate('createdBy')
    .then(eventWithUser => {
      ... // use result here
    })
    .catch(err => {
      ... // handle error here
    })
```

Comment: what about embedding documents ?

Comment: There is no need to embed events into user, if you do you will have another data structure.